# Ошибка при INSERT запросе psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Появилась следующая проблема при отправке запроса к бд

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "crossroad_id" of relation "api_accidents" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO api_accidents ("crossroad_id", "datetime_start",...
```

Методом проб, ошибок и сырых запросов к базе выяснилось, что ругань идет из-за кавычек в названии таблицы.

У меня реализован базовый класс для запросов к бд, и на его основе я делаю остальные для доступа к другим таблицам. Для другой таблицы схема работает, данные отправляются, проблем не возникает. Ниже указана функция отправки запроса к бд

```py
    def send(self, args):

        query = sql.SQL(self.query).format(
                sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, self.col_names)),
                sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Placeholder, self.col_names))
            )
        self.cursor.execute(query, args)
```

Так как метод базовый, в дочерних классах меняется только `col_names` и `query`, и с ними проблем нет.

Определяются они для этой схемы вот так внутри класса

```py
    query = """INSERT INTO api_accidents ({}) VALUES ({})"""
    col_names = ['crossroad_id', 'datetime_start', 'datetime_stop']
```

При сырых запросах вот такой SQL проходит

```sql
INSERT INTO api_accidents (сrossroad_id, datetime_start, datetime_stop)
    VALUES (1, current_timestamp, NULL)
```

А вот такой не проходит

```sql
INSERT INTO api_accidents ("сrossroad_id", "datetime_start", "datetime_stop")
    VALUES (1, current_timestamp, NULL)
```

Но стандартное форматирование `sql.SQL` делает второй вариант.

Можно ли как-то решить проблему, не вписывая напрямую названия столбцов без кавычек?

**UPDATE**

Проверил еще, в итоге выяснил, что от кавычек не зависит. Вот этот запрос выполняется независимо от того есть кавычки, или нет:

```sql
INSERT INTO api_accidents (сrossroad_id, datetime_start, datetime_stop)
    VALUES (1, current_timestamp, NULL);
```

А этот выдает ошибку независимо от того есть кавычки или нет:

```sql
INSERT INTO api_accidents (crossroad_id, datetime_start, datetime_stop)
    VALUES (1, current_timestamp, NULL);
```

И да, они полностью одинаковые. Но Postgres так не считает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге выяснилось, что второй разработчик на проекте, при создании бд каким-то образом умудрился указать русскую `с` в столбце `crossrad_id` вместо английской...

Поменяли название столбца в базе, все стало окей